# Number prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi everyone i need an help.
I try to modify Number.prototype to add the function sum.
I want to add some numbers to my initial number.

```js
Number.prototype.sum = async (...nums) => {
    var x = //What I have to write to have my inizial number here?
    for (var i = 0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        x=x+nums[i]
    }
    return x
}
console.log((10).sum(2)) // output: 12
console.log((10).sum(4,6)) // output: 20
```

(I use visual studio code and the hint after `this.` is only `number`)
I tried with:

```
Number.prototype.valueOf(this)

Number.prototype.valueOf(this.number)

Number.parseInt(this.toString())

Number.parseFloat(this.toString())

Number.parseInt(this.number.toString())

Number.parseFloat(this.number.toString())

this.valueOf()

this.number.valueOf()
```

Comment: Why is this method `async`? I don't really see a point of it being a method, either, but I suspect you're just exploring prototypes. Do be aware that changing built-in prototypes is *very* not recommended in real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `function` to access the correct `this` context (which is the number that the method is called on). Arrow functions inherit their `this` context from the parent scope (the global object in this case). Also `async` is not needed since you are not doing anything asynchronous here:

```js
Number.prototype.sum = function (...nums) {
    var x = this
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        x = x + nums[i]
    }
    return x
}

console.log((1).sum(2, 3))
```

Aside from the fact that augmenting native prototypes is a bad idea, wouldn't you think that a function like this is better suited for the `Array` prototype?

Comment: I forgot to remove async because I try with async/await, too.

Comment: I will try your hint